# Getting a Reference to a Zend_Application's Config Object

Tags: php, zend-framework, config, zend-application, zend-queue

Is there a helper method/object/methodology for getting a reference to a `Zend_Application`'s config resource?

I know I can do something like

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini($file, $environment);
```

but that's going to reload/parse the config file.  I'm looking for a way to peek at the given configuration value for a running `Zend_Application`.

The larger issue I'm trying to solve is I want a `Zend_Queue` to use the same database settings as my default database resource.  If there's a more "Zend Like" way of achieving this other than "get reference to config, read resource values" please feel free to share that as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    public function run()
    {
        // make the config available to everyone
        $config = $this->getOptions();
        Zend_Registry::set('config', new Zend_Config($config));
        parent::run();
    }
}
```

Zend_Queue

there is code in `Zend_Queue_Adapter_Db` __construct `if (isset($this->_options['dbAdapter']))` so u can do thomething like this

```
new Zend_Queue_Adapter_Db(array('dbAdapter' => Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter()));
```

because standart `Zend_Application_Resource_Db` can use config option `resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true`

or u can put db adapter in registry and get it from there at any place

Answer (score 1):

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam('bootstrap')->getOptions()
```